# Expressing ${n\choose{k}}$ As a Summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

I know that you can express ${n\choose{2}}$ as this sum: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2},$$
and ${n\choose{3}}$ as
$${n\choose{3}}= (n-2)1 + (n-3)2 + (n-4)3 +\cdots+3(n-4) + 2(n-3) + 1(n-2).$$
I got stuck with ${n\choose{4}}$, how would i go about finding a sum that expresses it?

More generally, can I find a sum for ${n\choose{k}}$?

Comment: The Hockey Stick Lemma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can write any $\binom{n}k$ as a sum because of the following identity:
$$\binom{n}k = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}k,$$
with obvious initial values $\binom{n}n = \binom{n}0 = 1$.

Proceeding for $\binom{n}4$ is an easy recursive exercise, since you have already calculated $\binom{n}3$.